# Время доступа к list

Tags: python, алгоритм

Привет. Вопрос в следующем. В python есть list. Например:

```
listExample = []
```

В таком случае, если я добавлю в список данные. Скажем, так:

```
for item in range(0, 20):
    listExample.append(item)
```

Каково время доступа к произвольному элементу `listExample`? Если время доступа `O(1)`, то почему эта структура называется списком? В противном случае, если время доступа иное, то есть ли структуры данных с временем доступа за `O(1)` в питонеб реализованные в `stdlib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Здесь](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) есть таблицы с временной сложностью различных операций для структур данных Python.

Можно увидеть, что время доступа к элементу списка в любом случае константное.

Comment: Странно, что этот объект называется списком.

Comment: а как он по вашему должен называться?) вообще список в python очень похож на вектор в C++. Вот ссылка на объяснение реализации list в CPython http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/